# Catching OpenCV exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV [`warpAffine`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpAffine(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) function. But for some reason it fails sometimes (approximately 1/10 tries). I want to see the actual exception that is thrown, but fore some reason I can't catch it. Is there something wrong with my try-catch block?:

```
//...
cout << "pos 1" << endl;
try
{
    cout << "pos 2" << endl;

    cv::warpAffine(rawImage, transformed, t, size, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);

    cout << "pos 3" << endl;
}
catch (const std::exception& e1)
{
    cerr << e1.what() << endl;
}
catch (const cv::Exception& e2) {
    cerr << e2.what() << endl;

}
```

Even if I just have one `catch` block it is not running into it. The console is always (in the cases it is not working) the following error:

[image]

So I'm not really after the issue with `warpAffine`, more about the try-catch at the moment.

Comment: This looks more like an application crash than a c++ exception thrown. Press debug to see what is wrong.

Comment: It could be an assertion which cannot be catched. For example, there is an assertion in warpAffine() to check the image is not empty. If you had any console output it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a stale topic but I think I know the answer from my own experiences.
cv::Exception inherits from std::exception. You need to move the cv::Exception catch ahead of std::exception, like this:

```
try {
...
} catch(const cv::Exception& ex) {
...
} catch(const std::exception& ex) {
...
} catch(...) { //everything else
}
```